# Why does a full client need to store the DAG?

Tags: hash-algorithm, ethash

The yellow paper says that miners and full clients must store the DAG dataset, but light clients can verify block headers by generating only a few necessary pages from the DAG.

It makes sense to me that this suggests more Ethash hashes are necessary for a full client than a light client. What is being hashed? Or is there another reason?

What hash function is used in the Merkle trees? If it is Ethash then it would make sense that a lot more hashing is necessary to check the validity there.

I have searched for hours for this information but I can't find it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi there. Can you specify which part of the Yellow Paper details what you've described above?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks On page 15 it says 
"Light clients store the  cache.   From  the  cache,  we  can  generate  a  dataset... each item in the dataset depends on only a small number
of items from the cache.  **Full clients and miners store the
dataset.**  The dataset grows linearly with time."